# convert time string to seconds in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a timeuntil string displayed as 12d 00:57:30 
ie. dd'd' hh:mm:ss

How would I convert that into number of seconds in javascript or jquery.

Comment: Have a look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).

Comment: I always recommend someone to use moment.js whenever possible. The normal Data object in javascript is such a hassle. @RocketHazmat +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this will not sound good for some, but if you don't want to use a plugin like moment.js. You could parse it like this (only for format dd'd' hh:mm:ss):

```
var days = parseInt(time.split('d ')[0]);
var hours = parseInt(time.split('d ')[1].split(":")[0]);
var mins = parseInt(time.split('d ')[1].split(":")[1]);
var secs = parseInt(time.split('d ')[1].split(":")[2]);

hours += days * 24;
mins += hours * 60;
secs += mins * 60;
```

secs will be the total

Comment: string plus number = string.

Comment: I'd suggest saving `time.split('d')` as a variable, so you don't need to call it over and over.  Also, you'd need to trim the space after the `'d'`, so I'd actually suggest using `time.split('d ')`.

Answer (score 1):

For things like this, I love [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).  It has something called "[durations](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/)" that would be perfect for this situation.

First, you'd need to parse your string into its pieces.  Since you know the format, we can use a regex.

```
var time = '12d 00:57:30';
var timeParts = time.match(/(\d+)d (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/);

if(timeParts !== null){
    var timeUntil = moment.duration({
        days: timeParts[1],
        hours: timeParts[2],
        minutes: timeParts[3],
        seconds: timeParts[4]
    });
    var timeSeconds = timeUntil.as('seconds');

    console.log(timeSeconds);  // 1040250
}
```