# Convert two dates difference into seconds

Tags: php

This is my PHP Code.

```
 date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata"); 
 $startdate=date("Y-m-d h:i:sa");
 $enddate = 2016/10/02 15:10:30;
 $diff=strtotime($enddate)-strtotime($startdate);
```

The date format is `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` and I want to have difference of `end date` and `start date` in seconds.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript date format conversion (full text date to unix time stamp)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28768845/javascript-date-format-conversion-full-text-date-to-unix-time-stamp)

Comment: Yo need to right string date in quotes like this  $enddate = "2016/10/02 15:10:30";

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24942625/convert-time-string-to-seconds-in-javascript-jquery

Comment: $diff=date("s",strtotime($enddate)-strtotime($startdate));

Comment: There's no question here. The title mentions jQuery, but that's Javascript, and you posted PHP code. What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

> var myDate = new Date(yourdateString);  var DateinSeconds
>   =myDate.getTime() / 1000;

**getTime()** gives milliseconds. Divide it by 1000 to get seconds as above.

Comment: Assalam waleikum sir. first of all thank you for your comment. But i don't understand what is someDate means?

Comment: @T.Raut I have updated my answer. Please see if it can help.